# How do I do an include in PHP while requesting the username

Tags: php

I currently have this:

```
<?php include 'include/head.php';?>
```

I am trying to add this onto it:

```
<?php echo $_GET["username"]; ?>
```

I have tried this:

```
<?php include 'include/head.php?username=$_GET["username"]';?>
```

How will I be able to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by doing this?

Comment: If you want to get `$_GET['username']` in head.php then you can access by doing `echo $_GET['username']`. This variable will be available in included file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass variable to local files when you include them. But the file you're including will have access to everything your parent script does so you shouldn't need to.

Instead, just include the file like this

```
<?php include 'include/head.php'; ?>
```

And then, inside of "head.php" start with this line:

```
<?php
$username = $_GET['username'];
```

You CAN pass variables to remote files when you include them...

```
<?php include 'http://www.example.com/file.php?foo=1&bar=2'; ?>
```

but that usually takes changes to the default php.ini settings.

The php page on include has examples of these: http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php